# Подскажите пожалуйста, как в Django из объекта формы (ModelForm) получить объект модели

Tags: python, django

Пишу тест - нужный ли пост был загружен  в форму.

Из response беру форму:

```
response = self.authorized_client.get(reverse('post:post_edit', kwargs={'post_id': '1'}))
форма = response.context.get('form')
```

Беру пост из базы:

```
пост_из_бд = PostModelTest.posts.get(pk=1)
```

И сравниваю: `assertEqual(форма, пост_из_бд)`.

Так вот вопрос - как мне из формы вытащить пост, который был в неё загружен?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
Получаю объект поста из формы следующим образом:

```
post_from_form = response.context.get('form').save(commit=False)
```

а сам пост из тестовой БД:

```
post = PostModelTest.posts.get(pk=PostModelTest.post.pk)
```

и спокойно сравниваю:

```
self.assertEqual(post_from_form, post)
```